# (Illustrator) Adjusting "text box" size when using text on path tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, font-size, text-on-path

I'm finding it difficult to resize a path that has text.

I don't want to have smaller font size but bigger "container" so that current or bigger font would fit into.

Following has text "My text just...": 
[image]

How could I expand that "container" or resize the path or whatever is suitable in this case to fit the text?
That small red plus sign does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You have essentially 4 options...

1. Reduce the size of the text
2. Change to a visually narrower typeface.
3. Change the options on the **Character Panel** to "squish" the type
   horizontally (bad choice) by reducing the horizontal scale.
4. Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to lengthen the path - click one end anchor point and drag it outward. Or hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key and click the path (so *only* the path is highlighted) then you can use the Bounding Box or Free Transform Tool to drag a handle and widen just the path. However, if you lengthen the path the degree of the arc is going to change. So you'll also need to adjust that after lengthening.